# Tf Idf not equal, when tf in two documents is the same

Tags: r, tm, tf-idf

Let me first give my understanding of the TfIdf measure:

TF(t) = (Number of times term t appears in a document) / (Total number of terms in the document)

IDF(t) = log_e(Total number of documents / Number of documents with term t in it)

[my source, and good explanation](http://www.tfidf.com/)

so there is 1 Idf measure for every word in a Corpus.

the Tf however 'exists' for every word and for every document in the Corpus.

assuming a word has Tf=1 in 2 documents, then the TfIdf should be the same for both words, right?

I wanted to check this out in R, here my code:

```
library(tm)

data("crude")

DTM <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude,control=list(weighting=weightTf))
DTM2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude,control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf))

M <- as.matrix(DTM)
M2 <- as.matrix(DTM2)

    > M2[7:15,7:9]
     Terms
Docs  "if        "is       "may
  237   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
  242   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
  246   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
  248   0 0.01153447 0.01500669
  273   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
  349   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
  352   0 0.03650470 0.00000000
  353   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
  368   0 0.00000000 0.00000000
> M[7:15,7:9]
     Terms
Docs  "if "is "may
  237   0   0    0
  242   0   0    0
  246   0   0    0
  248   0   1    1
  273   0   0    0
  349   0   0    0
  352   0   1    0
  353   0   0    0
  368   0   0    0
```

Why is the TfIdf not the same? Where is my fallacy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different because you weighted the DTM by weightTf & the DTM2 by weightTfIdf.

Because weightTfIdf is normalized this will affect the results. Typically that normalizing means adding 1 to the denominator to prevent division by zero issues .